# sortOrder on the basis of alphabets in cursorLoder

Tags: android, sql, cursor

I want to sort my table on the basis of alphabetically. I am able to do it by using this query

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),URI, null, null, null, COL_NAME);
```

But in this way i am getting results in this way.

```
A B C D ...Z a b c ....z.
```

I want my cursorLoder to return `A a B b C c ....Z z.`

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),URI, null, null, null, COL_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
COL_NAME + " collate nocase"
```